# Can I burn on DVD using Windows DVD Maker's command line options only?

Tags: windows-7, dvd-burning

Is possible to do it? I'd like to give a `.msdvd` project file, burn that project to DVD using [`WDM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_DVD_Maker)'s command lines. How can I do that?
I found some options like `-drive` which specific what drive uses when burning but not how to pass the project file and start the actual burning automatically.

**Edit:**

The close I get so far:

> DVDMaker foo.msdv -drive:D

But it doesn't do the burning, just start the application with the give project.